# Python re.sub multine text

Tags: python, regex

I have an xml file with hundreds wrong entries that look like this:

```
<dapRecord>
<dapName>
<value>UPPERCASE_VALUE</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
</dapRecord>
```

Those entries need to be changed to look like this:

```
<dapRecord>
<dapName>
<value>UPPERCASE_VALUE</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
<dapBasicView>
<dapSelection>
<dapPolicy>
<value>match-all</value>
</dapPolicy>
<attr>
<name>aaa.cisco.username</name>
<value>lowercase-value</value>
<operation>EQ</operation>
<type>caseless</type>
</attr>
</dapSelection>
</dapBasicView>
</dapRecord>
```

I'm trying to run an re.sub on this to replace the bad entry with a good entry:

```
import re
path = "myfilehere"
with open (path, 'r') as f: 
    xml_data = f.read()
f.closed

values = ["value-1", "value-2"]
for value in values:
    bad_entry = """<value>{}</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
</dapRecord>""".format(value.upper())

    good_entry = """<value>{}</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
<dapBasicView>
<dapSelection>
<dapPolicy>
<value>match-all</value>
</dapPolicy>
<attr>
<name>aaa.cisco.username</name>
<value>{}</value>
<operation>EQ</operation>
<type>caseless</type>
</attr>
</dapSelection>
</dapBasicView>
</dapRecord>""".format(value.upper(), value.lower())
    
    match = re.search(bad_entry, xml_data) #this works
    data = re.sub(match.group(0), good_entry, xml_data) #this does not work
    with open (path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
    f.closed
```

`re.search` finds my `bad_entry`, but I can't get it to actually replace the `bad_entry` with the `good_entry` in `re.sub`. I've tried a few different formats, like setting the bad_entry to this when doing re.sub:

```
match = "<value>{}</value>\n</dapName>\n<dapViewsRelation>\n<value>and</value>\n</dapViewsRelation>\n</dapRecord>".format(value.upper())
```

I'm not sure how to get re.sub to replace it properly.

Comment: Which word do you mean by "multine"?

Comment: Why do you not use an xml parsing library?

Comment: Your example works for me, do you maybe have regex characters in your input data? Otherwise I'd agree with above, when you have an exact match, `str.replace` can help with that, and as you're handling xml data, the `xml` library might be more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `re.sub()`. You have no regular expression patterns, you're doing exact match and replacement. So you can use `str.replace()`.

You also need to do all the replacements before rewriting the file. Otherwise you'll just have the result of the last replacement.

```
path = "myfilehere"
with open (path, 'r') as f: 
    xml_data = f.read()

values = ["value-1", "value-2"]
for value in values:
    bad_entry = """<value>{}</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
</dapRecord>""".format(value.upper())

    good_entry = """<value>{}</value>
</dapName>
<dapViewsRelation>
<value>and</value>
</dapViewsRelation>
<dapBasicView>
<dapSelection>
<dapPolicy>
<value>match-all</value>
</dapPolicy>
<attr>
<name>aaa.cisco.username</name>
<value>{}</value>
<operation>EQ</operation>
<type>caseless</type>
</attr>
</dapSelection>
</dapBasicView>
</dapRecord>""".format(value.upper(), value.lower())
    
    xml_data = xml_data.replace(bad_entry, good_entry)

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml_data)
```

Comment: Yea I was way over thinking it. This worked great. Thank for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For those that come here looking for `multiline` use of `re`, you can use `flags=re.DOTALL` to read and replace in the entire input and not just line ending in `\n`